# Swift and MIDI output

Tags: swift, midi

I'm trying to get started on a music app I want to write, and I can't get past step one - play a single note.  I eventually want to be able to play a sequence of notes, but one thing at a time....

I'm working in Swift with Xcode.  I know Swift has some built in MIDI capabilities built in, but I've primarily been working with AudioKit 3.

That said... I'm totally lost on this.  There is a similar post to this one already,  and I have tried that one.  It runs, but no sound comes out.  No errors.  I can only assume swift has changed in some way since it was posted.  Other examples I have found use only the AKOscillator instead of a soundbank, but the oscillator sounds terrible and I can't use that.  I prefer it to sound like a piano, or trumpet, or something remotely musical.

Does anyone have some working example code of just playing a single note?

Here are the two closest bits of code I've found online, that I think do something like what I want.

```
let sampler = AKSampler()
sampler.loadWav("Sounds/fmpia1")
let ampedSampler = AKBooster(sampler, gain: 3.0)
var delay  = AKDelay(ampedSampler)
delay.time = pulse * 1.5
delay.dryWetMix = 0.0
delay.feedback = 0.0
    let cMajor = [72, 74, 76, 77, 79, 81, 83, 84]
var mix = AKMixer(delay)
var reverb = AKReverb(mix)
AudioKit.output = reverb
AudioKit.start()
for note in cMajor {
        sampler.playNote(note)
        sleep(1)
}
```

The problem with this first one is I have no clue about that file that is loaded in line 2. sampler.loadWav("Sounds/fmpia1")?  Maybe this would work if I had that file, or at least understood what sort of file it is.

In the second example, I actually have a copy of the file in question (gs_instruments.dls), and the following code does successfully run without error, but it fails to actually produce a sound.  No idea why.  This is the one I found here on stackoverflow.

```
class PlaySomething{
    init(){
        initAudio()
    }

    func initAudio(){
        let engine = AVAudioEngine()
        let sampler = AVAudioUnitSampler()
        engine.attachNode(sampler)
        engine.connect(sampler, to: engine.outputNode, format: nil)
        guard let soundbank = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("gs_instruments", withExtension: "dls") else {
            print("Could not initalize soundbank.")
            return
        }
        let melodicBank:UInt8 = UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB)
        let gmHarpsichord:UInt8 = 6
        do {
            try engine.start()
            try sampler.loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL(soundbank, program: gmHarpsichord, bankMSB: melodicBank, bankLSB: 0)
        }catch {
            print("An error occurred \(error)")
            return
        }
        sampler.startNote(60, withVelocity: 64, onChannel: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried, but didn't work? We'd love to help you find a solution, but it'd be even better if we can help you understand why your original code didn't work.

Comment: Edited my post to include some example code!

Comment: Swift 101 problem. When initAudio() returns the engine is popped off the stack. BTW. I cover AVAudioUnitSampler in detail here: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/the-great-avaudiounitsampler-workout

Comment: Haha!  Oops!  Thanks Gene De Lisa!  I have seen your site quite a bit as I've tried to get this project moving.  This was a rather simple oversight, but I may be pestering you for more in depth stuff as I move forward.  Thanks again!